# After training, is the prediction of the neural network achieved by just forward propagating from input to output layer?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, prediction, activation-function, feed-forward

I made a simple feedforward neural net in matlab as follows:

```
mynet = feedforwardnet(5)
mynet.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'poslin'; % one hidden layer(5 neurons) with poslin = ReLU activation function
mynet.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'purelin'; % last layer has simply linear activation function
```

I want to train this Neural Network to learn a non-linear function that looks like this:
[Original function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfhKh.png). So basically it is a regression problem. We have two inputs(u1, u2), and one output(y).

The neural net is trained and now to estimate the output, we can simply do:

```
input = [3;2] % u1 = 3, u2 = 2
y_predicted = mynet([input]) % gives the output for a input
```

This gives y_predicted = 2.9155. Okay, that is fine. The prediction is good (Since, y_true = 3). But I don't understand how this value came.

And then when I manually checked it by forward propagation, I got different result.
That is, I extracted the final weights and biases after training by:

```
W1 = mynet.IW{1,1}; b1 = mynet.b{1}; W2 = mynet.LW{2,1}; b2 = mynet.b{2}
```

Then did forward propagation:

```
Z1 = W1*[3; 2] + b1; 
A1 = poslin(Z1); % applying ReLU activation function 
Z2 = W2*A1 + b2;
A2 = Z2; % linear activation function
y_predicted = A2;
```

Now I get (y_predicted = 2.2549). Not that of a good prediction here, but I understand how this value came.

Shouldn't both predicted values be the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes they should be, you are likely not simulating your network well.

Comment: You were right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to the preprocessing of the input and output, which happens by default when you create a feedforward net in Matlab. So when checking it manually, we were not taking this into account and giving direct the raw data.

[Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/385206-why-is-predicting-the-output-of-a-trained-neural-network-by-using-net-sim-different-than-manually#answer_307446)

The problem was resolved after deactivating them by:

```
mynet.input.processFcns = {}; 
mynet.output.processFcns = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y_predicted = 2.9155
```

is not a metric(hence not accuracy). It is a number estimated by your model. If you are trying to approximate some function then you need to compute `Mean squared error` or root `mean squared error`. Suppose your input value was `3`(in this case `y_true = 3`) and your predicted value is `2.9155` then your `MSE = 0.00714`. So if MSE is low then your model will approximate the function better.

Now coming to your question: During training, backpropagation is used to correct the weights/errors due to those weights. However, during testing/predicting phase we do not adjust the weights. Hence, it is only forward step.

**Accuracy can never be higher than 1. It is a value between 0 and 1 and it is used in classification case. You are using regression and you need to compute MSE as explained above. The lower the MSE is the better your model is.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes the MSE is less with 'y_predicted = 2.9155', but I don't understand how the neural net simulated this result. On the other hand, 2.2549 gives higher MSE, but I understand how the value came (by forward prop)

Comment: @NeelabhJyotiSaharia is it possible that you stop editing the question after getting an answer so that we can follow.  Linear (purelin) has also bias. It is `a.x + b`, so when you compute manually, where is your bias?

Comment: No, purelin(or any activation function) doesn't have an extra bias. 'b2' has already been added in 'Z2'.